# Обновление списка в for in JS

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, есть функция, в которой

```
if (el.className === 'img') {
    replaceAlt(el);
    return images.push(el)
}
```

Эта функция периодически вызывается.
Также есть цикл, который работает всегда и перебирает элементы массива **images**

```
for (const image of images) {
    image.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        console.log(images);
        event.target.style.boxShadow = '0px 0px 22px 7px rgb(28 255 0)';
        const newAlt = prompt('Enter new alt');
        if (newAlt !== null) {
            event.target.alt = newAlt;
        }
    });
}
```

В console.log в цикле выводится массив с добавленным элементом, но клик на этот элемент не воспринимается.
Как сделать, чтобы новый элемент также отслеживался?

Comment: почитайте про [Делегирование событий](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9+js) возможно и от цикла откажетесь, в любом случае если добавляете события не забывайте и удалять иначе будет утечка памяти

Comment: еще [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRLJ3rJEWmQ) можете глянуть

Comment: Спасибо большое, самое то)